# Upper limit of fromstring function in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm using Python 2.4 version on a Windows 32-bit PC. I'm trying to parse through a very large XML file using the ElementTree module. I downloaded version 1.2.6 of this module from effbot.org.

I followed the below code for my purpose:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

input = ''' 001 Chuck 009 Brent '''
stuff = ET.fromstring(input)
lst = stuff.findall("users/user")
print len(lst)

for item in lst:
    print item.attrib["x"]

item = lst[0]
ET.dump(item)
item.get("x") # get works on attributes
item.find("id").text
item.find("id").tag

for user in stuff.getiterator('user'):
    print "User" , user.attrib["x"]

ET.dump(user)
```

If the content of input is too large, more than 10,000 lines, the `fromstring` function raises an error (below). Can anyone help me out in rectifying this error?

This is the error generated:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Documents and Settings\hariprar\My Documents\My files\Python Try\xml_try1.py", line 16, in -toplevel- stuff = ET.fromstring(input) File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 1012, in XML return api.fromstring(text) File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 182, in fromstring parser.feed(text) File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 1292, in feed self._parser.Parse(data, 0) ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2445, column 39

Comment: Please format you code when posting questions. I have edited the code the reflect what I think you were trying to post, please edit it if I didn't get it quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `iterparse` function. It will let you parse your input incrementally rather than reading it into memory as one big chunk.

It's described here: http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm